# pythonanywhere relative path and absolute path error for the tensorflow library

Tags: tensorflow, directory, subdirectory, pythonanywhere, absolute-path

i am getting this code to perfectly in VSCODE but when i use this code in pythonanywhere it is always having some issues.

I resolved it with using sys.path and it worked for me.

but when the flask code is run, and get adn post request are sent at that time i am getting some tensorflow error.

Steps to reproduce.

```
https://github.com/experience-ml/cartoonize.git
```

```
cd cartoonize
```

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

flask code shall run but then there are directory error for it. and i tried the minified the code and used absolute path but then now i am getting some tensorflow libraries to  not work.

this is the error i am getting

```
2024-02-05 05:50:33 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5629901dee50
```

```
2024-02-05 05:50:33 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections 2024-02-05 05:50:33 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds 2024-02-05 05:50:33 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes 2024-02-05 05:50:33 mapped 334256 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores 2024-02-05 05:50:33 *** Operational MODE: single process *** 2024-02-05 05:50:33 initialized 38 metrics 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:25.029450: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:25.029470: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine. 2024-02-05 05:50:33 111111111111111111111 /home/shahhtejas/mysite/config.yaml 2024-02-05 05:50:33 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py:1694: UserWarning: `layer.apply` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.#012 warnings.warn('`layer.apply` is deprecated and ' 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:33.328003: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations: AVX2 AVX512F FMA#012To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:33.336705: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/../../lib64: 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:33.336722: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303) 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:33.336742: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (green-liveweb3): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist 2024-02-05 05:50:33 2024-02-05 05:50:33.356572: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled 2024-02-05 05:50:33 Weights successfully loaded 2024-02-05 05:50:33 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 11 seconds on interpreter 0x5629901dee50 pid: 1 (default app) 2024-02-05 05:50:33 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode *** 2024-02-05 05:50:33 gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1) 2024-02-05 05:50:33 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22, cores: 1) 2024-02-05 05:50:33 metrics collector thread started 2024-02-05 05:50:33 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1 2024-02-05 05:50:55 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor... for this code in pythonanywhere what should i do for this ?
```

and this is the code that i am running for app.py

i have my all the network.py , cartoonizer.py in the site-package as a workaround and even did the changes to the directory pointing and this is the final code

`import os`
`import io`
`import uuid`
`import sys`
`import yaml`
`import traceback`
`from markupsafe import Markup`
`import tensorflow as tf`

`sys.path.insert(0, './home/shahhtejas/mysite/white_box_cartoonizer/')`

`from white_box_cartoonizer.cartoonize import WB_Cartoonize`

`# /home/shahhtejas/files/mysite/myfile.txt`
`from pathlib import Path`
`THIS_FOLDER = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()`
`my_file = THIS_FOLDER / "config.yaml"`

`print("111111111111111111111",my_file)`

`with open(my_file, 'r') as fd:`

`opts = yaml.safe_load(fd)`

`sys.path.insert(0, './home/shahhtejas/mysite/white_box_cartoonizer/')`

`import cv2`
`from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response, flash`
`import flask`
`from PIL import Image`
`import numpy as np`
`from white_box_cartoonizer.cartoonize import WB_Cartoonize`

`from flask_cors import CORS`
`app = Flask(__name__)`
`CORS(app, origins = '*')`
`app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER_VIDEOS'] = 'static/uploaded_videos'`
`app.config['CARTOONIZED_FOLDER'] = 'static/cartoonized_images'`

`app.config['OPTS'] = opts`
`# wb_cartoonizer = WB_Cartoonize(os.path.abspath("white_box_cartoonizer/saved_models/"), opts['gpu'])`
`home_directory = os.path.expanduser("~")`

`# Define the path to the weights directory`
`weights_directory = os.path.join(home_directory, "mysite/white_box_cartoonizer/saved_models/")`

`# Initialize the WB_Cartoonize object`
`wb_cartoonizer = WB_Cartoonize(weights_directory, opts['gpu'])`

`def convert_bytes_to_image(img_bytes):`

`pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))`
    `if pil_image.mode=="RGBA":`
        `image = Image.new("RGB", pil_image.size, (255,255,255))`
        `image.paste(pil_image, mask=pil_image.split()[3])`
    `else:`
        `image = pil_image.convert('RGB')`

`image = np.array(image)`

`return image`

`@app.route('/')`
`@app.route('/cartoonize', methods=["POST", "GET"])`
`def cartoonize():`
    `opts = app.config['OPTS']`
    `if flask.request.method == 'POST':`
        `try:`
            `if flask.request.files.get('image'):`
                `img = flask.request.files["image"].read()`
                `image = convert_bytes_to_image(img)`
                `print("32222222222222222222",image)`
                `img_name = str(uuid.uuid4())`
                `print("img_name",img_name)`
                `cartoon_image = wb_cartoonizer.infer(image)`

`cartoonized_img_name = os.path.join(app.config['CARTOONIZED_FOLDER'], img_name + ".jpg")`
                `cv2.imwrite(cartoonized_img_name, cv2.cvtColor(cartoon_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))`

`if not opts["run_local"]:`

`output_uri = upload_blob("cartoonized_images", cartoonized_img_name, img_name + ".jpg", content_type='image/jpg')`
                    `print(output_uri)`

`os.system("rm " + cartoonized_img_name)`
                    `cartoonized_img_name = generate_signed_url(output_uri)`
                    `print(cartoonized_img_name)`
                `return cartoonized_img_name`

`except Exception:`
            `print(traceback.print_exc())`
            `flash("Our server hiccuped :/ Please upload another file! :)")`
            `return "Error"`
    `else:`
        `return "Please use POST method to upload the image"`

`if __name__ == "__main__":`
    `app.run(debug=False, host='127.0.0.1', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))`

i need to know what should i do for tensor flow library and how to solve that error for the tensor flow directory error to point to the location just like it does in VS code and not in the pythonanywhere.com code

Comment: It's not how you should run a web app on PythonAnywhere, see [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/) on how to set up a Flask app on PA.  Also you may encounter issues regarding machine learning code, see [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MachineLearningInWebsiteCode/) for more details.